# Adding form view causes tree records disappear

Tags: acumatica

I added form view to ContactMaint Graph.
It works fine and show records of related contact nicely, however records in Attributes tab disappeared.
I use AcumaticaERP 5.1

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CR.MassProcess;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.CR;

namespace PX.Objects.CR
{

    public class ContactMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ContactMaint>
    {

        [PXHidden]
        public PXSelectJoin<Contact,
            LeftJoin<BAccount,
            On<Contact.contactID, Equal<BAccount.defContactID>>>,
            Where<BAccount.bAccountID,                       Equal<Current<Contact.bAccountID>>>>
            DefContact;
    }


}
```

Comment: which form do you use?

Comment: Organization/Customer management/Contacts  and open contact CR.30.20.00. I added view there as form